# SQL Server - SQL Select issue because of multi datatype where clause

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a problem while writing a Sql command on SQL Server 2008 R2.
The fact is that I have numeric and nvarchar data stored in a same column (IMP_VALUE).
When I try to execute this command

```
Select count(*)  
from IMPORTBM   
    inner join ATTRIBUTE on ATT_ATTRIBUTE_ID = IMP_ATTRIBUTE_ID   
where IMP_LOCATION_ID = 1   
    AND IMP_SERIAL_ID = 58   
    AND IMP_VERSION_ID = 1   
    AND   
        ((ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBHT' AND IMP_VALUE = 'NA')   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBLOPK' AND IMP_VALUE = 'NA')   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'BRGLWLNG' AND IMP_VALUE = 0.603)   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'MSZ' AND IMP_VALUE IN ('LMV-321','LMV-322'))   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBACCK' AND IMP_VALUE IN ('NA','WARNING_NoValueFound'))   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBTHLWLOC' AND IMP_VALUE IN ('NA','WARNING_NoValueFound')))
```

, it fails with the error :

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Of course, I've changed this in order to make this work

```
CAST(IMP_VALUE as numeric) = 0.603
```

BUT it's not.

When I execute only the first part of the command, everything works fine

```
Select count(*)  
from IMPORTBM   
    inner join ATTRIBUTE on ATT_ATTRIBUTE_ID = IMP_ATTRIBUTE_ID   
where IMP_LOCATION_ID = 1   
    AND IMP_SERIAL_ID = 58   
    AND IMP_VERSION_ID = 1   
    AND   
        ((ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBHT' AND IMP_VALUE = 'NA')   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBLOPK' AND IMP_VALUE = 'NA')   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'BRGLWLNG' AND CAST(IMP_VALUE as numeric) = 0.603))
```

But when I add the 3 last lines of the `where` :

```
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'MSZ' AND IMP_VALUE IN ('LMV-321','LMV-322'))   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBACCK' AND IMP_VALUE IN ('NA','WARNING_NoValueFound'))   
        OR  (ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'GBTHLWLOC' AND IMP_VALUE IN ('NA','WARNING_NoValueFound')))
```

, it fails with the same error code than before!
Does someone know why it's only working without the `in` lines please?
Also, would you have something to make that work?
Many thanks !

Comment: If your field is a VARCHAR, then why are you not doing `AND IMP_VALUE = '0.603'`?  That would avoid the query trying to convert a row with `'NA'` in it to a NUMERIC before comparing to `0.603`...

Comment: Because I can use several operators (such as >, < >=, <=, in, not in, between) and this `where` clause is dynamic, it creates itself with numeric and varchar values, depending on what my user want. (I'm not sure to be clear, my english is quite poor...)

Comment: Then you're relying on short circuiting; the optimiser knowing to not apply `CAST(IMP_VALUE AS NUMERIC)` when the `ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'BRGLWLNG'` condition fails.  eithe rthat short-circuiting is failing due to the complexity of your WHERE clause, or you have values in `IMP_VALUE` that are not numeric even when `ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'BRGLWLNG'`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well, but I'm sure that when `ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'BRGLWLNG'` , I only have numeric values. Remember that the first part of my select is working well (including the `CAST(IMP_VALUE AS NUMERIC)`. It's only when I add the three other lines with `IN` clauses that it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this query and see if both values are real numeric values...

```
SELECT MIN(IMP_VALUE), MAX(IMP_VALUE) FROM ATTRIBUTE WHERE ATT_ATTRIBUTE = 'BRGLWLNG';
```

I'm pretty sure you have values in there that CAN'T be converted to `NUMERIC`.

Either your `OR` needs to filter them out, or you need to fix those values so that they're properly formatted string representations of `NUMERIC`.

Also, note that you are just using `NUMERIC`, and the sql server help pages say that this is just the same as `NUMERIC(18,0)`; 18 digits, with no digits after the decimal place.  Try a more appropriate data type *(the following is a brute force option)*...

```
OR  (    ATT_ATTRIBUTE                     = 'BRGLWLNG'
     AND ISNUMERIC(IMP_VALUE)              = 1
     AND CAST(IMP_VALUE AS NUMERIC(38,19)) = 0.603
)
```

Comment: the first query returns : 1.400 1.400

Comment: And the second thing you asked me to do works perfectly !! Thanks !! But then why wasn't this working when I tried with float datatype ?

Comment: @KrasshX - What about it wasn't working?  Wrong results, error message?

Comment: Oops never mind I was wrong, it was something else ! ^^' Many thanks for your help !